# Windows Server Locking Up

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure

Server running Windows 7 SP1 keeps locking up every few days, and has to be rebooted. When it happens, I can still ping the server, but am unable to connect via RDP or VNC until after the reboot. Event Log shows nothing - literally a gap from about 10p last night, until the reboot this morning. Chkdsk and SFC show no problems.

It's a remote server, so I'm not able to see what it looks like before the reboot, and the person rebooting is not tech savvy.

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible one of the RAM memory modules is going bad.

Try walking user through running "mdsched.exe" (Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool) from Start Menu, which will reboot Windows into Memory Test mode.

Unfortunately, you can't run remotely.  If you haven't tried it, run it first so you know what to expect.

MemTest86 is another option, but it also requires CD/USB boot.

Comment: Thanks. We have coverage for the server, so I ultimately dispatched a tech to repair or replace it. I was just curious about the possible causes for this, and if there was anything more I could check remotely. I've used MemTest86 quite a bit, but I didn't know about the Windows Mem Diag Tool. That's interesting.

Comment: By the way, I was able to run mdsched remotely. Results are in the System event log.